# Bold text in MessageBox

Tags: c#, winforms, messagebox

How can I show the text in bold in the dialog displayed by `MessageBox.Show`, using C#?

Comment: I know it's been a while but with SO being as much for current problems as for posterity please do select an answer – also as a way of honouring those who took the time to respond.

Answer (score 32):

It is possible, a message box is a regular window that can be messed with like any other.  The code to do so is however a bit gritty.  Add a new class to your project and paste this code:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

class BoldMessageBox : IDisposable {
  private int mTries = 0;
  private Form mOwner;
  private Font mFont;

  public BoldMessageBox(Form owner) {
    mOwner = owner;
    owner.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(findDialog));
  }

  private void findDialog() {
    // Enumerate windows to find the message box
    if (mTries < 0) return;
    EnumThreadWndProc callback = new EnumThreadWndProc(checkWindow);
    if (EnumThreadWindows(GetCurrentThreadId(), callback, IntPtr.Zero)) {
      if (++mTries < 10) mOwner.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(findDialog));
    }
  }
  private bool checkWindow(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr lp) {
    // Checks if <hWnd> is a dialog
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(260);
    GetClassName(hWnd, sb, sb.Capacity);
    if (sb.ToString() != "#32770") return true;
    // Got it, get the STATIC control that displays the text
    IntPtr hText = GetDlgItem(hWnd, 0xffff);
    if (hText != IntPtr.Zero) {
      // Get the current font
      IntPtr hFont = SendMessage(hText, WM_GETFONT, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
      Font font = Font.FromHfont(hFont);
      // And make it bold (note the size change to keep enough space!!)
      mFont = new Font(font.FontFamily, font.SizeInPoints - 1f, FontStyle.Bold);
      SendMessage(hText, WM_SETFONT, mFont.ToHfont(), (IntPtr)1);
    }
    // Done
    return false;
  }
  public void Dispose() {
    mTries = -1;
    mOwner = null;
    if (mFont != null) mFont.Dispose();
  }

  // P/Invoke declarations
  private const int WM_SETFONT = 0x30;
  private const int WM_GETFONT = 0x31;
  private delegate bool EnumThreadWndProc(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr lp);
  [DllImport("user32.dll")]
  private static extern bool EnumThreadWindows(int tid, EnumThreadWndProc callback, IntPtr lp);
  [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
  private static extern int GetCurrentThreadId();
  [DllImport("user32.dll")]
  private static extern int GetClassName(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder buffer, int buflen);
  [DllImport("user32.dll")]
  private static extern IntPtr GetDlgItem(IntPtr hWnd, int item);
  [DllImport("user32.dll")]
  private static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, IntPtr wp, IntPtr lp);
}
```

And use it like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  using (new BoldMessageBox(this)) {
    MessageBox.Show("Nobugz waz here");
  }
}
```

There is one flaw in this approach.  After making the font bold, the text must still fit in the static control that the message box reserved for the text.  That required me to make the font smaller.  You may have to tweak this value.

Answer (score 8):

You can't. This is a wrapper for the API [MessageBoxEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645505%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Create your own custom messagebox to do it.

---

You can follow [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/A_Custom_Message_Box.aspx) tutorial, as an example of how to implement one.

The basics steps of creating such a form:

1. Create a new form
2. Add a label and two buttons
3. Set the label font to Bold
4. add handler to both buttons, closing the form and setting some property for which button was pressed.

Comment: Thanks, can you suggest some steps for that?

Comment: yup, even added some basics steps as a guide line.

Comment: MessageBox is a form that wraps the MessageBoxEx. If you look closely, it is either a modal or modeless dialog box based on a Form. You can create your own class yourself to emulate the same behavior

Answer (score 0):

No can do. You'll have to build your own box. I'm assuming that this is WinForms, if it's ASP.NET I'm not qualified to answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Extended MessageBox .NET Assembly** 
[XMSG .NET web page: more info, download](http://www.news2news.com/vfp/?solution=5)

Adjusts on the fly wide variety of MessageBox visual settings.

Adjustable features include message font and color, button captions, fonts and tooltips, dialog background, dialog position, dialog icon, timeout and more. Depending on message font selected, the dialog window automatically resizes itself to accommodate  the message.

Additional controls that can be optionally displayed: check box, text input, web link, up to 3 extra buttons.

In your .NET code you still call regular MessageBox.Show. Extended MessageBox is not a custom-made dialog. This is still regular MessageBox with extended features added.

OS supported: XP, 2000, 2003, 2008 Vista, Win7 -- 32 or 64-bit.

Downloads include fully-functional trial version, and regular version with complete C# source code.