# How to change default setting of font dialog in c#

Tags: c#, fonts

1. How to change default font dialog script from "Western" to "Arabic"?  After set AllowScriptChange to false, replace Arabic to Western in font dialog.
2. How to prevent of show Strikeout & Underline in Effects `FontDg.ShowEffects = false` but show of Color is true?  How can I show color without effects?

Thanks.

Comment: These options are not available, not in FontDialog and not in the low-level Windows API function (ChooseFont) either.  Technically you can hack around that limitation with the approach shown in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2259213/17034

Answer (score -2):

_fontDialog.ShowDialog ();
Var test = _fontDialog.Font.GdiCharSet.GetHashCode();

// will get you started. Trace it [step-into] and watch the test value change in a watch list in Debug mode to discover the rest.

Answer (score -3):

```
/* Okay, sorry I didn't have more time for this the other day.
 * But there is a very simple/eloquent solution for this that will
 * leave you wondering why you didn't think of it. AND...
 * Such is programming LoL.
*/

// Say I have existing code something like:

PrintFont = PrintMasterSettings.Default.PrintFont;

/* 
* Where PrintSettings.Default.PrintFont is persistent storage for PrintFont.
* Fine & dandy. The PrintFont gets brought back in, size, style, everything
* BUT The Script Selection. Am I close to the problem a lot of people have
* here Much YET?  ROFL. And try as you might you can't SET; the GdiCharSet
* value Because _fontDialog.Font.GdiCharSet has no SETTER. Right?  Been
* there done much more than that. No t-shirt... but I did figure it out in
* about ten minutes after sleeping on it.
*
* What to charge for the answer and who to sell it to?  LOL. Give up yet???
* Well, I have an "advantage" in that I'm self-taught. Think out of that box
* most programming profs have never done much programming. True fact.
* So how to do it is alluding you because you are trying to do it the
* "right way" and, instead, should be focused on doing it period.
*
* "Some way, GdiCharSet my ***; MAKE IT GD work!" the boss said. 
* "Searching StackOverflow says it can't be done." I said. 
* "Prove them wrong!" he said. "If you buy lunch?" I said with finality.
* "Fine!" he said. ***I had a Nice thick and rare New York steak!
*
*/

// Okay, So now I simply call my special custom method like so:

PrintFont = GetFontWithScript();

// Okay, I mean don't feel dumb. Things don't always work in .NET...
// NOT like you'd think they should. But there is usually a simple way.
// I'm thinking it's an indexer to a collection right. But no it's just as
// Gd simple. LoL  Enjoy! (yes, this really works. The initial value for
// PrintSettings.Default.GdiCharSet should be set to 1 btw.)

// Then somewhere before your _fontDialog.ShowDialog(); you have:

_fontDialog.Font = PrintFont;

// Right...  But the big money is in the method. Check in the mail? LoL
// Promise you won't feel dumb? Because you're not, you made it to here!
// You searched it and found someone who knew. That's pretty smart!
// Nobody around here even knows what I'm on about mate. G'day.
// JpE@ facebook-dot-com/JpESystems/

// Okay here it is... This should help a lot of peeps. 
// Please mark This ANSWER AS USEFUL if it helps you guys and gals out.
//\\//\\//\\//\\//\\//\\\//\\//\\//\\//\\//\\//\\//\\//\\//\\//\\//\\//\\

private Font GetFontWithScript()
{
  PrintFont   = PrintMasterSettings.Default.PrintFont;
  var name    = PrintFont.Name;
  var size    = PrintFont.Size;
  var style   = PrintFont.Style;
  var unit    = PrintFont.Unit;
  var charSet = PrintMasterSettings.Default.GdiCharSet;// byte value btw.

  return new Font(name,size,style,unit,charSet);
  /*
  * Font(String, Single, FontStyle, GraphicsUnit, Byte) 
  * Initializes a new Font using a specified size, style, 
  * unit and character set.
  * 
  */
}
```