# how can i make a string variable's font colour red in a messagebox from c# code?

Tags: c#, winforms

i have this code

```
public static bool Delete(int ID, string ProductName)
    {
        if (MessageBox.Show(productName + " will be deleted Permanently ", "Confirm Delete Option", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning) == DialogResult.No)
            {
                return false;
            }
        {
            return true;
        } 
    }
```

what i need to is make **productName** in messagebox below red in colour

```
if (MessageBox.Show(productName + " will be deleted Permanently "
```

Comment: I'm afraid you will have to make your own custom message box

Comment: You can't do that have to make one yourself. See: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winforms/thread/7e5b9237-7502-4eba-aaed-48ebce2ce8a7 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2259027/bold-text-in-messagebox

Comment: @SQL.NET What has `html` got to do with the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That can't be done with MessageBox.

You need to define your own form with the layout as you like and then show it modally.

Answer (score 5):

You have to create your own Form for this.
In there you create one label and define your font.
After that you can define your `no` and `yes` Button.

```
private void No_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.DialogResult = DialogResult.No;
    this.Close();
    this.Close();
}
```

The same for the `yes` button
There are multiple other advantages by creating your own form e.g. defining position.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to make your own MessageBox to make this possible. It's simple as creating a form and then chaning the ForeColor with Visual Designer or with System.Drawing.Color = http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.aspx