# Which is the mathematic formula to calculate the size and positions for this window?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, resize, position

> INTRODUCTION:

I'm using a custom messagebox class which was originally written by @Hans Passant here: [Winforms-How can I make MessageBox appear centered on MainForm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2576156/winforms-how-can-i-make-messagebox-appear-centered-on-mainform)

(The modified version that I'm using is at bottom of this question)

The custom messagebox can receive a custom text font to display it.

This is an usage example:

```
Using New CenteredMessageBox(Me, _
      New Font(New FontFamily("Lucida Console"), 16, FontStyle.Bold))

 MessageBox.Show("Test Text", "Test Title", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question)

End Using
```

> THE PROBLEM:

All the contents of the window need to be resized/positioned manually, if not, the text will de displayed cropped like this:

[image]

And this is the result If I use bigger fonts (I've resized the text control):

[image]

So I need to calculate which position and size would have the elements realatively to the font size, to resize the window and to positionate the buttons, and that is what I'm asking for. How I can do it? I would need more than a just formula 'cause mathematics i do not do much well.

> THE ELEMENTS:

I have these elements in mind:

- The Messagebox text-font size.
- The Messagebox static control that contains and displays the text.
- The Messagebox button(s) (which can be a combination of 1 button, 2 buttons, or 3 buttons, with different default positions)
- The Messagebox Window Form which contains all these elements.

Button(s) variables:

- If only is 1 buton in messagebox window (ex: 'Ok') it will be alligned to middle, but if they are 3 buttons (ex: 'AbortRetryIgnore') then the first button will be alligned to down left corner, the second button to middle and the last button to the right corner, I think there is no need to explain this 'cause all knows how the msgbox displays their buttons.

I'm not an arithmetic guru, so forgive me if I miss some necessary values, but I think that these would be the necessary values/variables in the code to work with:

```
Dim Text_width As Integer = 0
Dim Text_height As Integer = 0

Dim Text_Container_width As Integer = 0
Dim Text_Container_height As Integer = 0

' Don't calculate the exact size of messagebox window,
' just I think only needs to sum an extra size to a default messagebox rectangle 
Dim Messagebox_window_extra_width As Integer = 0
Dim Messageboxwindow_extra_height As Integer = 0

' This represents the first button,
' in a messagebox button combination of 1, 2, or 3 buttons,
' this button could be displayed alligned at bottom-middle (as unique button), 
' or could be alligned at bottom-left (as the first of 2 of 3 button combination).
Dim Button_1_Pos_X As Integer = 0
Dim Button_1_Pos_Y As Integer = 0

' This button represents the second button
' in a messagebox button combination of 2 or 3 buttons,
' the buton could exist or could not
' and could be displayed alligned at bottom-middle (in the middle of 3 buttons),
' this button could be displayed alligned at bottom-right (as second and last button). 
Dim Button_2_Pos_X As Integer = 0 
Dim Button_2_Pos_Y As Integer = 0

' This button represents the third button 
' a messagebox button combination of 2 or 3 buttons,
' the buton could exist or could not
' and could be displayed alligned at bottom-right (as third and last button).
Dim Button_3_Pos_X As Integer = 0
Dim Button_3_Pos_Y As Integer = 0
```

This is what I could did by myself, I've been testing to store the messagebox button elements in this way:

```
Dim button_Ok As IntPtr = GetDlgItem(hWnd, 1)     ' The 'Ok'     button.
Dim button_Cancel As IntPtr = GetDlgItem(hWnd, 2) ' the 'Cancel' button.
Dim button_Abort As IntPtr = GetDlgItem(hWnd, 3)  ' the 'Abort'  button.
Dim button_Retry As IntPtr = GetDlgItem(hWnd, 4)  ' the 'Retry'  button.
Dim button_Ignore As IntPtr = GetDlgItem(hWnd, 5) ' the 'Ignore' button.
Dim button_Yes As IntPtr = GetDlgItem(hWnd, 6)    ' the 'Yes'    button.
Dim button_No As IntPtr = GetDlgItem(hWnd, 7)     ' the 'NO'     button.
```

(Their always have the same Item index no matter the messagebox buton combination)

To resize the messagebox window I can use the MoveWindow API like this:

```
     ' This is to resize and positionate the messagebox window
    MoveWindow(hWnd, _
               frmRect.Left + (frmRect.Width - dlgRect.Right + dlgRect.Left) \ 2, _
               frmRect.Top + (frmRect.Height - dlgRect.Bottom + dlgRect.Top) \ 2, _
               (dlgRect.Right - dlgRect.Left) + Messagebox_window_extra_width, _
               (dlgRect.Bottom - dlgRect.Top) + Messagebox_window_extra_height, True)
```

And to resize the rest elements (text container, buttons), after resizing the messagebox form then I can use the SetWindowPos API like this:

```
  ' Text container:
   SetWindowPos(hText, 0, 70, 30, 1920, 1080, 0) ' Values are not perfect calculated but works fine 

  ' Messagebox buttons:
  ' SetWindowPos(button_Ok, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0) 
  ' SetWindowPos(button_Cancel, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
  ' SetWindowPos(button_Abort, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
  ' SetWindowPos(button_Retry, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0) 
  ' SetWindowPos(button_Ignore, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0) 
  ' SetWindowPos(button_Yes, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0) 
  ' SetWindowPos(button_No, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

> THE MESSAGEBOX CLASS

Here is messed up all the things that I've mentioned before:

```
' [ Centered MessageBox ]
'
' The author of the original code is Hans Passant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2576156/winforms-how-can-i-make-messagebox-appear-centered-on-mainform
'
' Examples :
'
' Using New CenteredMessageBox(Me, New Font(New FontFamily("Lucida Console"), Font.SizeInPoints, FontStyle.Bold))
'     MessageBox.Show("Test Text", "Test Title", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
' End Using

#Region " Centered MessageBox Class"

Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Class CenteredMessageBox : Implements IDisposable

    Private mTries As Integer = 0
    Private mOwner As Form
    Private mFont As Font

    Dim Text_width As Integer = 0
    Dim Text_height As Integer = 0

    Dim Text_Container_width As Integer = 0
    Dim Text_Container_height As Integer = 0

    Dim Messagebox_window_extra_width As Integer = 0
    Dim Messagebox_window_extra_height As Integer = 0

    Dim Button_1_Pos_X As Integer = 0 ' "OK" Button
    Dim Button_1_Pos_Y As Integer = 0 ' "OK" Button

    Dim Button_2_Pos_X As Integer = 0 ' This button could not exist
    Dim Button_2_Pos_Y As Integer = 0 ' This button could not exist

    Dim Button_3_Pos_X As Integer = 0 ' This button could not exist
    Dim Button_3_Pos_Y As Integer = 0 ' This button could not exist

    ' P/Invoke declarations
    Private Const WM_SETFONT As Integer = &H30
    Private Const WM_GETFONT As Integer = &H31

    Private Delegate Function EnumThreadWndProc(hWnd As IntPtr, lp As IntPtr) As Boolean

    <DllImport("user32.dll")> _
    Private Shared Function EnumThreadWindows(tid As Integer, callback As EnumThreadWndProc, lp As IntPtr) As Boolean
    End Function

    <DllImport("kernel32.dll")> _
    Private Shared Function GetCurrentThreadId() As Integer
    End Function

    <DllImport("user32.dll")> _
    Private Shared Function GetClassName(hWnd As IntPtr, buffer As StringBuilder, buflen As Integer) As Integer
    End Function

    <DllImport("user32.dll")> _
    Private Shared Function GetDlgItem(hWnd As IntPtr, item As Integer) As IntPtr
    End Function

    <DllImport("user32.dll")> _
    Private Shared Function SendMessage(hWnd As IntPtr, msg As Integer, wp As IntPtr, lp As IntPtr) As IntPtr
    End Function

    <DllImport("user32.dll")> _
    Shared Function GetWindowRect(hWnd As IntPtr, ByRef rc As RECT) As Boolean
    End Function

    <DllImport("user32.dll")> _
    Shared Function MoveWindow(hWnd As IntPtr, x As Integer, y As Integer, w As Integer, h As Integer, repaint As Boolean) As Boolean
    End Function

    Structure RECT
        Public Left As Integer
        Public Top As Integer
        Public Right As Integer
        Public Bottom As Integer
    End Structure

    Friend Declare Function SetWindowPos Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, ByVal hWndInsertAfter As IntPtr, ByVal x As Integer, ByVal y As Integer, ByVal cx As Integer, ByVal cy As Integer, ByVal wFlags As UInt32) As Boolean

    Public Sub New(owner As Form, Optional Custom_Font As Font = Nothing)
        mOwner = owner
        mFont = Custom_Font
        owner.BeginInvoke(New MethodInvoker(AddressOf findDialog))
    End Sub

    Private Sub findDialog()

        ' Enumerate windows to find the message box
        If mTries < 0 Then
            Return
        End If

        Dim callback As New EnumThreadWndProc(AddressOf checkWindow)

        If EnumThreadWindows(GetCurrentThreadId(), callback, IntPtr.Zero) Then
            If System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment(mTries) < 10 Then
                mOwner.BeginInvoke(New MethodInvoker(AddressOf findDialog))
            End If
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Function checkWindow(hWnd As IntPtr, lp As IntPtr) As Boolean

        ' Checks if <hWnd> is a dialog
        Dim sb As New StringBuilder(260)
        GetClassName(hWnd, sb, sb.Capacity)
        If sb.ToString() <> "#32770" Then Return True

        ' Got it, get the STATIC control that displays the text
        Dim hText As IntPtr = GetDlgItem(hWnd, &HFFFF)
        ' Get the messagebox button elements
        Dim button_Ok As IntPtr = GetDlgItem(hWnd, 1)     ' The 'Ok'     button.
        Dim button_Cancel As IntPtr = GetDlgItem(hWnd, 2) ' the 'Cancel' button.
        Dim button_Abort As IntPtr = GetDlgItem(hWnd, 3)  ' the 'Abort'  button.
        Dim button_Retry As IntPtr = GetDlgItem(hWnd, 4)  ' the 'Retry'  button.
        Dim button_Ignore As IntPtr = GetDlgItem(hWnd, 5) ' the 'Ignore' button.
        Dim button_Yes As IntPtr = GetDlgItem(hWnd, 6)    ' the 'Yes'    button.
        Dim button_No As IntPtr = GetDlgItem(hWnd, 7)     ' the 'NO'     button.

        Dim frmRect As New Rectangle(mOwner.Location, mOwner.Size)
        Dim dlgRect As RECT
        GetWindowRect(hWnd, dlgRect)

        If hText <> IntPtr.Zero Then

            If mFont Is Nothing Then
                ' Get the current font
                mFont = Font.FromHfont(SendMessage(hText, WM_GETFONT, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero))

            End If

            SendMessage(hText, WM_SETFONT, mFont.ToHfont(), New IntPtr(1))

            ' Just here is an empty space where I can test some operations:
            '
            ' Messagebox_window_extra_width = (mFont.Height \ mFont.Size) + (dlgRect.Right)
            ' Messagebox_window_extra_height = mFont.Height +

            ' This is to resize and positionate the messagebox window:
            MoveWindow(hWnd, _
                       frmRect.Left + (frmRect.Width - dlgRect.Right + dlgRect.Left) \ 2, _
                       frmRect.Top + (frmRect.Height - dlgRect.Bottom + dlgRect.Top) \ 2, _
                       (dlgRect.Right - dlgRect.Left) + Messagebox_window_extra_width, _
                       (dlgRect.Bottom - dlgRect.Top) + Messagebox_window_extra_height, True)

            ' And this is to resize and positionate the rest elements:
            '
            ' Text container:
            SetWindowPos(hText, 0, 70, 30, 1920, 1080, 0)
            '
            ' Messagebox buttons:
            ' SetWindowPos(button_Ok, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0) 
            ' SetWindowPos(button_Cancel, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
            ' SetWindowPos(button_Abort, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
            ' SetWindowPos(button_Retry, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0) 
            ' SetWindowPos(button_Ignore, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0) 
            ' SetWindowPos(button_Yes, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0) 
            ' SetWindowPos(button_No, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)

        End If

        ' Done
        Return False

    End Function

    Public Sub Dispose() Implements IDisposable.Dispose
        mTries = -1
        mOwner = Nothing
        If mFont IsNot Nothing Then mFont.Dispose()
    End Sub

End Class

#End Region
```

> UPDATE

This is what I get trying to use @Grahamvs solution:

[image]

```
   Using New CenteredMessageBox(Me, New Font(New FontFamily("Lucida Console"), Font.SizeInPoints, FontStyle.Bold))
        MessageBox.Show("Test Text", "Test Title", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
    End Using
```

Comment: Use the Win32 function GetTextExtent to determine the HxW of whatever text you want to measure.  The NET equivalent is `graphics.MeasureString` which is may be more appropriate here.  ( didnt read the whole WOT).  Did you try am AutoSize Label for this?

Comment: @Plutonix Hi, Thankyou for the API function information, I will give it a try when I can get time to test it, the default messagebox label does not have autosize, or at least if I change the text it won't resize, but then you are meaning that I can change the autosize property from other external formulary?, if yes, how?, maybe that will simplify much things, thankyou again.

Comment: @Plutonix no way to see how to use GetTextExtent, the function is noton pinvoke.net also I've read that the function is for C/C++, I can't find any relatod to that function in vb.net and the graphics.MeasureString I don't know how to use it

Comment: It is a series of gdi32.dll functions: `GetTextExtentExPoint`, `GetTextExtentPoint`, `GetTextExtentPoint32`.  The NET equivalent is `graphics.MeasureString`...where does MS say it is for C?  If it is in the API you can call it (with varying degrees of hurdles).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked for me:

I changed:

```
 <DllImport("user32.dll")> _
Private Shared Function SendMessage(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal msg As Integer, ByVal wp As IntPtr, ByVal lp As IntPtr) As IntPtr
End Function
```

to

```
 Declare Auto Function SendMessage Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal msg As Integer, ByVal wParam As IntPtr, ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As IntPtr
```

and add (after `SendMessage(hText, WM_SETFONT, mFont.ToHfont(), New IntPtr(1))`)

```
        ' Get text
        Dim WM_GETTEXT As Integer = &HD

        ' Alloc memory for the buffer that recieves the text
        Dim Hndl As IntPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(200)

        ' Send The WM_GETTEXT Message
        Dim NumText As Integer = SendMessage(hText, WM_GETTEXT, 200, Hndl)

        ' Copy the characters from the unmanaged memory to a managed string
        Dim MSGText As String = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(Hndl)


        ' Measure the text
        Dim TextSize As SizeF
        Using G As Graphics = mOwner.CreateGraphics
            TextSize = G.MeasureString(MSGText & "MMM", mFont)
        End Using
```

and changed `MoveWindow` to:

```
MoveWindow(hWnd, frmRect.Left + (frmRect.Width - dlgRect.Right + dlgRect.Left) \ 2, frmRect.Top + (frmRect.Height - dlgRect.Bottom + dlgRect.Top) \ 2, CInt(TextSize.Width) + Messagebox_window_extra_width, (dlgRect.Bottom - dlgRect.Top) + Messagebox_window_extra_height, True)
```

Hope this helps

Edit: Here is the full code

```
' [ Centered MessageBox ]

'

' The author of the original code is Hans Passant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2576156/winforms-how-can-i-make-messagebox-appear-centered-on-mainform

'

' Examples :

'

' Using New CenteredMessageBox(Me, New Font(New FontFamily("Lucida Console"), Font.SizeInPoints, FontStyle.Bold))

'     MessageBox.Show("Test Text", "Test Title", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)

' End Using



#Region " Centered MessageBox Class"



Imports System.Drawing

Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Imports System.Text

Imports System.Windows.Forms



Class CenteredMessageBox : Implements IDisposable

    Private mTries As Integer = 0

    Private mOwner As Form

    Private mFont As Font



    Dim Text_width As Integer = 0

    Dim Text_height As Integer = 0



    Dim Text_Container_width As Integer = 0

    Dim Text_Container_height As Integer = 0



    Dim Messagebox_window_extra_width As Integer = 0

    Dim Messagebox_window_extra_height As Integer = 0



    Dim Button_1_Pos_X As Integer = 0 ' "OK" Button

    Dim Button_1_Pos_Y As Integer = 0 ' "OK" Button



    Dim Button_2_Pos_X As Integer = 0 ' This button could not exist

    Dim Button_2_Pos_Y As Integer = 0 ' This button could not exist



    Dim Button_3_Pos_X As Integer = 0 ' This button could not exist

    Dim Button_3_Pos_Y As Integer = 0 ' This button could not exist



    ' P/Invoke declarations

    Private Const WM_SETFONT As Integer = &H30

    Private Const WM_GETFONT As Integer = &H31



    Private Delegate Function EnumThreadWndProc(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal lp As IntPtr) As Boolean



    <DllImport("user32.dll")> _

    Private Shared Function EnumThreadWindows(ByVal tid As Integer, ByVal callback As EnumThreadWndProc, ByVal lp As IntPtr) As Boolean

    End Function



    <DllImport("kernel32.dll")> _

    Private Shared Function GetCurrentThreadId() As Integer

    End Function



    <DllImport("user32.dll")> _

    Private Shared Function GetClassName(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal buffer As StringBuilder, ByVal buflen As Integer) As Integer

    End Function



    <DllImport("user32.dll")> _

    Private Shared Function GetDlgItem(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal item As Integer) As IntPtr

    End Function



    '<DllImport("user32.dll")> _

    'Private Shared Function SendMessage(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal msg As Integer, ByVal wp As IntPtr, ByVal lp As IntPtr) As IntPtr

    'End Function



    <DllImport("user32.dll")> _

    Shared Function GetWindowRect(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByRef rc As RECT) As Boolean

    End Function



    <DllImport("user32.dll")> _

    Shared Function MoveWindow(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal x As Integer, ByVal y As Integer, ByVal w As Integer, ByVal h As Integer, ByVal repaint As Boolean) As Boolean

    End Function



    Declare Auto Function SendMessage Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal msg As Integer, ByVal wParam As IntPtr, ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As IntPtr



    Structure RECT

        Public Left As Integer

        Public Top As Integer

        Public Right As Integer

        Public Bottom As Integer

    End Structure



    Friend Declare Function SetWindowPos Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As IntPtr, ByVal hWndInsertAfter As IntPtr, ByVal x As Integer, ByVal y As Integer, ByVal cx As Integer, ByVal cy As Integer, ByVal wFlags As UInt32) As Boolean



    Public Sub New(ByVal owner As Form, Optional ByVal Custom_Font As Font = Nothing)

        mOwner = owner

        mFont = Custom_Font

        owner.BeginInvoke(New MethodInvoker(AddressOf findDialog))

    End Sub



    Private Sub findDialog()



        ' Enumerate windows to find the message box

        If mTries < 0 Then

            Return

        End If



        Dim callback As New EnumThreadWndProc(AddressOf checkWindow)



        If EnumThreadWindows(GetCurrentThreadId(), callback, IntPtr.Zero) Then

            If System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment(mTries) < 10 Then

                mOwner.BeginInvoke(New MethodInvoker(AddressOf findDialog))

            End If

        End If



    End Sub



    Private Function checkWindow(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal lp As IntPtr) As Boolean



        ' Checks if <hWnd> is a dialog

        Dim sb As New StringBuilder(260)

        GetClassName(hWnd, sb, sb.Capacity)

        If sb.ToString() <> "#32770" Then Return True



        ' Got it, get the STATIC control that displays the text

        Dim hText As IntPtr = GetDlgItem(hWnd, &HFFFF)

        ' Get the messagebox button elements

        Dim button_Ok As IntPtr = GetDlgItem(hWnd, 1)     ' The 'Ok'     button.

        Dim button_Cancel As IntPtr = GetDlgItem(hWnd, 2) ' the 'Cancel' button.

        Dim button_Abort As IntPtr = GetDlgItem(hWnd, 3)  ' the 'Abort'  button.

        Dim button_Retry As IntPtr = GetDlgItem(hWnd, 4)  ' the 'Retry'  button.

        Dim button_Ignore As IntPtr = GetDlgItem(hWnd, 5) ' the 'Ignore' button.

        Dim button_Yes As IntPtr = GetDlgItem(hWnd, 6)    ' the 'Yes'    button.

        Dim button_No As IntPtr = GetDlgItem(hWnd, 7)     ' the 'NO'     button.



        Dim frmRect As New Rectangle(mOwner.Location, mOwner.Size)

        Dim dlgRect As RECT

        GetWindowRect(hWnd, dlgRect)



        If hText <> IntPtr.Zero Then



            If mFont Is Nothing Then

                ' Get the current font

                mFont = Font.FromHfont(SendMessage(hText, WM_GETFONT, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero))



            End If



            SendMessage(hText, WM_SETFONT, mFont.ToHfont(), New IntPtr(1))



            ' Get text

            Dim WM_GETTEXT As Integer = &HD



            ' Alloc memory for the buffer that recieves the text

            Dim Hndl As IntPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(200)



            ' Send The WM_GETTEXT Message

            Dim NumText As Integer = SendMessage(hText, WM_GETTEXT, 200, Hndl)



            ' Copy the characters from the unmanaged memory to a managed string

            Dim MSGText As String = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(Hndl)





            ' Measure the text

            Dim TextSize As SizeF

            Using G As Graphics = mOwner.CreateGraphics

                TextSize = G.MeasureString(MSGText & "MMM", mFont)

            End Using



            ' Just here is an empty space where I can test some operations:

            '

            ' Messagebox_window_extra_width = (mFont.Height \ mFont.Size) + (dlgRect.Right)

            ' Messagebox_window_extra_height = mFont.Height +



            ' This is to resize and positionate the messagebox window:

            'MoveWindow(hWnd, frmRect.Left + (frmRect.Width - dlgRect.Right + dlgRect.Left) \ 2, frmRect.Top + (frmRect.Height - dlgRect.Bottom + dlgRect.Top) \ 2, _

            ' (dlgRect.Right - dlgRect.Left) + Messagebox_window_extra_width, (dlgRect.Bottom - dlgRect.Top) + Messagebox_window_extra_height, True)

            MoveWindow(hWnd, frmRect.Left + (frmRect.Width - dlgRect.Right + dlgRect.Left) \ 2, frmRect.Top + (frmRect.Height - dlgRect.Bottom + dlgRect.Top) \ 2, Math.Max(CInt(TextSize.Width), 200) + Messagebox_window_extra_width, (dlgRect.Bottom - dlgRect.Top) + Messagebox_window_extra_height, True)



            ' And this is to resize and positionate the rest elements:

            '

            ' Text container:

            SetWindowPos(hText, 0, 70, 30, 1920, 1080, 0)

            '

            ' Messagebox buttons:

            ' SetWindowPos(button_Ok, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)

            ' SetWindowPos(button_Cancel, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)

            ' SetWindowPos(button_Abort, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)

            ' SetWindowPos(button_Retry, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)

            ' SetWindowPos(button_Ignore, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)

            ' SetWindowPos(button_Yes, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)

            ' SetWindowPos(button_No, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)



        End If



        ' Done

        Return False



    End Function



    Public Sub Dispose() Implements IDisposable.Dispose

        mTries = -1

        mOwner = Nothing

        If mFont IsNot Nothing Then mFont.Dispose()

    End Sub


End Class

    #End Region
```

Comment: Thankyou, please post the full class, I've changed the things that you've said but I'm getting a small MessageBox Window where I can't see the text

Comment: @ElektroStudios, I've updated my post to include the full class

Comment: @ElektroStudios, I've re-updated the code to ensure that the width will always be 200 or more