# Equivalent of (IntPtr)1 in VBNET?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, intptr, code-translation

I've taken a piece of code from a @Hans Passant code from here: [Bold text in MessageBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2259027/bold-text-in-messagebox/2259213#2259213)

this is the C# code:

```
SendMessage(hText, WM_SETFONT, mFont.ToHfont(), (IntPtr)1)
```

Which would be the translation into vb.net?

This will not work (cant be compiled):

```
SendMessage(hText, WM_SETFONT, mFont.ToHfont(), DirectCast(1, IntPtr))
```

Comment: What is the compilation error?

Comment: can't cast Integer to System.IntPtr

Comment: @Douglas Barbin yes that's the compilation error thankyou for saying it.

Comment: DirectCast is not a general-purpose conversion of the C# cast operator.  The relationship between the type and the item being casted has to be one of inheritance or implementation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
SendMessage(hText, WM_SETFONT, mFont.ToHfont(), New IntPtr(1))
```