# Is my code properly translated from C# to Vb.Net?

Tags: c#, vb.net

I found a possible solution for creating a Wizard-like (next/previous) Form, in this answer: [Creating Wizards for Windows Forms in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340566/creating-wizards-for-windows-forms-in-c-sharp)

```
class WizardPages : TabControl
{
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        // Hide tabs by trapping the TCM_ADJUSTRECT message
        if (m.Msg == 0x1328 && !DesignMode) m.Result = (IntPtr)1;
        else base.WndProc(ref m);
    }        

    protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs ke)
    {
        // Block Ctrl+Tab and Ctrl+Shift+Tab hotkeys
        if (ke.Control && ke.KeyCode == Keys.Tab) 
            return;
        base.OnKeyDown(ke);
    }
}
```

The solution allows me to create Tabs in Designer, and hide them at Runtime. I tried to translate this to VB.NET, and worked with:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Public Class WizardPages
    Inherits TabControl

    Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As System.Windows.Forms.Message)
        If (m.Msg = 4904 And Not DesignMode) Then '4904 is Dec of 0x1328 Hex
            m.Result = IntPtr.Zero 'IntPtr1
        Else
            MyBase.WndProc(m)
        End If

    End Sub

End Class
```

The only part that I didn't translate (but still works) is the `m.Result = (IntPtr)1;` from the C# code. As you can see, I tried with `m.Result = IntPtr.Zero`

For the moment I don't know what will happen if I leave it like that.

Comment: See [Equivalent of (IntPtr)1 in VBNET?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19283287/231316)

Comment: Also worked by replacing to: `m.Result = New IntPtr(1) 'IntPtr1`. Still I don't know what it does.

Comment: Looking at [`TCM_ADJUSTRECT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760573(v=vs.85).aspx) on MSDN, that message actually isn't expecting a return value so I think this is a little bit of a no-op. There's a much longer discussion on return values at [What does the Result property of a windows message mean and when and how to use it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19961694/231316). If you inspect `m.Result` before setting it, what do you get?

Comment: I think you are translating in the wrong direction :O

Comment: Perhaps? To be honest, I don't know what it does that `m.Result = (IntPtr)1; ` in C#

Answer (score 2):

Combining your answer with @Usman's yields the following.  To get 1 as an IntPtr, I used the `new IntPtr(1)` syntax which should work.  Alternatively `CType(1, IntPtr)` should also work.  I have not tested either, however.

Imports System
    Imports System.Windows.Forms

```
Public Class WizardPages
  Inherits TabControl

  Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As System.Windows.Forms.Message)
    If m.Msg = &H1328 AndAlso Not DesignMode Then
      m.Result = new IntPtr(1)
    Else
      MyBase.WndProc(m)
    End If

  End Sub

  Protected Overrides Sub OnKeyDown(ke As KeyEventArgs)
    ' Block Ctrl+Tab and Ctrl+Shift+Tab hotkeys
    If ke.Control AndAlso ke.KeyCode = Keys.Tab Then Return
    MyBase.OnKeyDown(ke)
  End Sub
End Class
```