# WPF C# How to make textbox.text bold in ced behind?

Tags: c#, wpf

How to make "textboxUsername.text" text bold in this example?

```
MessageBox.Show("Username " + textBoxUsername.Text + " already exists! Please choose another one.", "Message");
```

Thanks.

Comment: make a customize messageBox, read about it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6932792/how-to-create-a-custom-messagebox)

Comment: You can't do it natively. This might help. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2259027/bold-text-in-messagebox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2259027/bold-text-in-messagebox)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is no possible, as the MessageBox API exposes to text-formatting options.

The best way is to create your own form and make it look like a message box (this isn't so hard, it's just a modal dialog with a button on it).

Answer (score 1):

Check this out:

[Bold Some Text in MessageBox](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a670f198-24e5-4199-ae7a-e064a9a38232/bold-some-text-in-messagebox?forum=csharpgeneral)